# Javascript promise with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am implementing an API to manage a MySQL database from Nodejs, and I want to keep my code clean as the work I intend to do can take me to have a lot of nested connection.query functions all over the place, so I've decided to separate as many as the queries I could into separate functions.

To start I wanted to do a function to check if there is an existing element already on the table, like this:

```
function validator(item) {
    return new Promise(function(err,done) {
    connection.query('select * from items where item_id = ?', [item.id] , function(err,rows){
        console.log(rows);
        console.log("above row object");
        if (err) {
            return done(false);
        }
        if (rows.length) {
            console.log('That item is already in the DB.');
            return done(false);
        } else {
            console.log('That item is new.');
           return done(true);
        } 
    });
});
}
```

And then I want to use it like this:

```
    var insert = function (item, done) {
    validator(item).then(function(err,done) {
        console.log('here I go: '+done);
        if(done) {
            console.log('good');
        } else{
            console.log('bad')
        }
      );
    }
```

But it does not work like I expected, the first function accurately detects if an item exists or not, but the second one never never reaches the "here I go" print.

I have checked [Use promise to process MySQL return value in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547292/use-promise-to-process-mysql-return-value-in-node-js), [Javascript Promise node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845624/javascript-promise-node-js) and [Javascript & promises with Q - closure problems in promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294791/javascript-promises-with-q-closure-problems-in-promises) but the conclussion I reach is that this is a classic PEBCAK problem, such as that I'm a very incompetent javascript programmer and can't wrap my head around the callbacks and promises all that well so I'm managing them the wrong way.

Comment: `return new Promise(function(err,done) {` ? That's not how promises work.

Answer (score 1):

The first callback you pass to the [Promise constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) isn't the failing one.

Change

```
return new Promise(function(err,done) {
```

into

```
return new Promise(function(done, reject) {
```

and call it like this:

```
validator(item).then(function(done) {
```

(by the way it's very confusing to call `done` both the resolve callback and the result).

Handle the incoming error: Change

```
if (err) {
        return done(false);
}
```

into

```
if (err) {
        reject(err);
}
```

and don't forget to catch those errors.

Also, it's probably outside the scope of this QA but you usually take and release connections. You should probably have a look at promises ready mysql drivers.

Comment: This seems to have helped me, but now my print console.log('here I go: '+done); always tells me "here I go undefined", shouldn't 'done' be 'true' as the return on the callback when an item does not exist? Also yeah I know I need to release the connections, this is just a small test of concept.

Comment: @DanielOrtiz I edited to point a few other problems. And I suggest renaming that "done".

Comment: Thank you a lot, your pointers helped me solve the problem, in fact the last part was a product of me being tired as I was using validator(item).then(function(err,done) { instead of validator(item).then(function(done, err) { and as such the 'done' was undefined.